# Mutable массивы и память

Tags: массивы, objective-c, память

Моя функция создает и возвращает массив сложной структуры - `NSMutableDictionary`, в нем элементы - `NSMutableArray`, а в них еще - `NSMutableDictionary`. Я просто возвращаю при помощи `return` этот главный `NSMutableDictionary` (хотя мне нужно возвращать NSDictionary, но я заметил что и так работает).

Но, похоже, вся эта конструкция сильно потребляет память, т.е. память занимаемая приложением постоянно увеличивается, и мне кажется что именно из-за этого. Что можно с этим сделать? Превратить всю эту конструкцию из `Mutable` в простую? Если да, то как, только созданием новой переменной и всей структуры?

Обновление: переделал код чтобы возвращались только неизменяемые массивы, но все равно память понемногу увеличивается

```
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *main_dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *row in [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^\\s*([0-9]+)\\s+([0-9\\.]+)\\s+([0-9]+)\\s+(.+)$" options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:row options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [row length])];for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches )
    {

        str1 = [row substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
        str2 = [row substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:4]];

        if([str isEqualToString:str1])
            continue;

        num1 = [[row substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]] floatValue]/100.0;
        num2 = [[row substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:3]] floatValue]/1000.0;

        [list addObject:@{
                            @"KEY1": str1,
                            @"KEY2": str2,
                            @"KEY3": [row substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]],
                            @"KEY4": [row substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:3]],
                            @"NUM1": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num1],
                            @"NUM2": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num2],
                            }];

    }

}

/************************ Sorting ************************/

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                            sortDescriptorWithKey:@"NUM1"
                            ascending:NO
                            selector:@selector(compare:)
                            ];

[list sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

[main_dict setObject:[list subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,6)] forKey:@"NUM1"];

sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                  sortDescriptorWithKey:@"NUM2"
                  ascending:NO
                  selector:@selector(compare:)
                  ];

[list sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

[main_dict setObject:[list subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,6)] forKey:@"NUM2"];

return [main_dict copy];
```

Comment: Зачем тебе изменяемые массивы и дикшенари? В это есть необходимость? Покажи код

Comment: Да, есть. Я сортирую NSMutableArray, а в конечных NSMutableDictionary потом еще добавляю новые значения в цикле.

Comment: сталкивался с подобными конструкциями только при обработке JSON, возможно надо заняться проектированием моделей, без кода ничего дельного посоветовать не могу

Comment: А что в этом плохого? Т.е. создаю массив определенной вложенности и структуры, потом его сортирую, потом дополняю его некими значениями. На php я это делаю каждый день, здесь такой подход неработоспособен? Т.е. там где бы я использовал символьные ключи на php, использовал здесь NSMutableDictionary, где цифровые - NSMutableArray. В общем, все хорошо и быстро работает, и достаточно просто, все кроме того, что память увеличивается.

Comment: @Алексей Алыбин, добавил фрагмент кода, теперь уже без mutable, но память все равно по чуть-чуть увеличивается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не могу точно сказать на сколько изменяемый массив/дикшенари занимает больше памяти чем неизменяемые, но мне кажется это пораноя - если много данных в дикшенери, то и памяти много.
Посмотри с помощью инструментов утечки и выделение памяти. Можно точно определить когда и сколько выделяется памяти. Можно еще попробовать в финальный дикшенери и масивы присвать неизменяемые копии:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
// заполняем, сортируем массив a
NSArray *finishA = [a copy]; // finishA будет неизменяемым
```

Comment: Да, так я умею :) Только у меня вложенность там NSMutableDictionary - NSMutableArray - NSMutableDictionary. И интересует ответ про память, из-за  этого память увеличивается, из-за того, что функция возвращает все это вместо обычного NSDictionary?

Comment: Инструменты я как-то пробовал - там масса информации выводится, только я не смог из нее выделить мне нужную, т.е. не нашел в этих инструментах какая именно переменная в коде занимает сколько памяти - там все адреса какие-то, а для чего они мне не пойму.

Comment: :) С инструментами надо разобраться, иначе никак. Там все просто на самом деле.
Странный вопрос. Память увеличивается, потому что объекты присваиваются в массивы и дикшенари. Пока какой-то объект ссылается на массив, все объекты в этом массиве будут жить. Как только ссылка на массив оборвется, массив и все объекты в нем будут удалены из памяти. Когда ты делаешь копию из изменяемого в неизменяемый, изменяемый будет удален из памяти и все его объекты будут также удалены.

Comment: Да, я вобщем уже так и предполагал, что надо в неизменяемый массив преобразовать перед тем как возвращать. Но инструменты эти - жуть, ну их :) Есть график потребления памяти, по нему и буду смотреть.